# How can I set a different homepage per language in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

How can I set a different homepage per language in Drupal ?

I'm only using locale module (not i18.. or other translations module).

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without path module in a very simple fashion:

First of all, go to sites/default/settings.php and define the frontpage as multilingual variable:

```
$conf['i18n_variables'] = array('site_frontpage');
```

After that, clear cache and go to admin > Site Information. You will see that below "Default front page" there will be: "This is a multilingual variable.":
[image]

change the admin language (usually there is a block of language switcher in the sidebar) and change the path, The path will be different for each language.

You can add more i18n_variables to change other things in site information according to language i.e site name, slogan, mission. more information at:

Comment: I guess I need i18 module for this. I'm just using locale. Is there a way to do it, just with locale ? thanks

Comment: @Patrick - You have to use i18n module for that. I make a lot of multilingual sites (including RTL sites) and it is very convenient module.

Answer (score 0):

And if you want this to actually work, because there's an annoying bug in setting a default homepage for different languages, as we're used to having ridicolous bugs in Drupal, you have to change the url in orde to properly set the default front page. This is because the language prefix remains the same when switching languages. Amazing isn't it.

So change /nl/admin/config/system/site-information to /en/admin/config/system/site-information

To actually make this work.