# Drupal 7: different homepage template for different language

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a site on Drupal7 using multilingual plugin.
I have 4 languages and I need to make a completely different homepage for one of langugaes (let's say Russian version).

I followed these articles:
[How can I set a different homepage per language in Drupal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213748/how-can-i-set-a-different-homepage-per-language-in-drupal)
https://www.drupal.org/node/1216132

They work only partially. Because now my Russian homepage:

- has content of the choosen node (that's right)
- has template (page--front.tpl.php) of the front page instead of the appropriate template.

And it creates unwanted effect: I have the right content in the page view.

I don't know if a former developer of the website made it or it's a drupal mistake.

Could anybody give me a hint, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, all what you want is to use different page templates for different languages? This can easily be done in your `MODULE_preprocess_page` or `THEME_preprocess_page` function:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $language = $variables['language'];
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__front__' . $language->language;
}
```

Now the system will search for `page--front--en.tpl.php` etc. templates.

The function `mytheme_preprocess_page` can be found in:
*/sites/all/themes/mytheme/template.php*

Also take a look at [Working with template suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/223440#custom-suggestions).

Comment: Stanislav, thank you. It helped.
In the end, I had to choose a different solution regarding to other customizations, but it works.